# How to deploy initial data on database tables through flyway

Tags: database, flyway

I am using flyway to migrate my database schema and I feel it is really powerful to keep my database instances schemas update. Now I have a new requirement that I need some initial data on tables when release my application. Whether I can use flyway to do that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular migration with insert statements.

Comment: Will it be inserted multiple times?