# Initialize database only on one profile via Flyway

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, flyway

I am trying to enable initialization of a database (execution of .sql file containing INSERT statements) in application that uses Spring, Hibernate and Flyway.

The issue is that I want this initialization to be performed only on 'local' profile and to be entirely skipped on 'production' (so [How to deploy initial data on database tables through flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002298/how-to-deploy-initial-data-on-database-tables-through-flyway) doesn't solve it).

If the app weren't using Flyway, I could achieve this conditional initialization by simply using `spring.datasource.data=initialization_script.sql` in 'local' profile and putting all the inserts inside such file. I don't know how to do such things in Flyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway has an option to use profile-specific configurations. Some migrations can be performed conditionally only when a particular profile is active.

To do this one can use (as example):
`spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration,classpath:/local/db/migration` in properties file. With this setup migrations from 'local/db/migration' are run only if 'local' profile is active